# entity framework InMemoryDatabase context.Entity,Add() exception with incorrect key

Tags: entity-framework-core

In the seeding stage of Integration Tests I am adding "Cottages".

Each Cottage has a CottageId, which is set up in IEntityTypeConfiguration's `Configure` method as `builder.HasKey(x => x.CottageId);`

Two entities have different CottageIds but the same CottageCode.

I am a bit baffled as to why I get the exception below on `context.Cottages.Add` for the second entity, when the key (CottageId) is different for each, and CottageCode is NOT the key:

> The instance of entity type 'Cottage' cannot be tracked because
> another instance with the key value '{CottageCode: 3728}' is already
> being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
> entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Is the in-memory db making it's own decision about what is they key? If so how can I correct it?

Comment: First, integration tests should use actual db, not in-memory. Second, in-memory db does *not* make it's own decisions except if you explicitly configure it differently. With that being said, all I can say is that if EF Core says `CottageCode` is the key, then there is something in your code which tells it to think that way. You need to find that out, or post a reproducible example model/configuration/code which works with real db and does not work with in-memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @ivan-stoev I looked a lot harder.

In the configuration for another entity I had

```
builder.HasOne(x => x.Cottage).WithMany(x => x.CottageAccessRights)
  .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.CottageCode)
  .HasForeignKey(x => x.CottageCode);
```

HasPrincipalKey adds a unique constraint on CottageCode.

Reworking the relationship solved the issue.